# Contest problem involving primes and factorization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Prove that for any nonnegative integer $n$, the number
$$5^{5^{n+1}}+ 5^{5^{n}}+1$$
is not prime.

I want only some hints and the method to follow, but I don't need the full solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $x = 5^{5^{n}}$ in the factorisation
$$x^5+x+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)$$
to obtain a factorization of the number $5^{5^{n+1}}+ 5^{5^{n}}+1$. Then it should not be difficult for you to prove that both factors are greater than $1$.

**References**:

1. T. Andreescu and D. Andrica, *$360$ Problems for Mathematical Contests*, GIL, 2003.
2. R. Gelca and T. Andreescu, *Putnam and Beyond*, Springer, 2007.

Comment: Thank you for the references too!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

If $x=5^{5^n}, 5^{5^{n+1}}=(5^{5^n})^5=x^5$

Use [Factorizing polynomial $x^5+x+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106837/factorizing-polynomial-x5x1)

Comment: @user140619, My Pleasure. From  the link, we can say that $$x^{3m+2}+x^{3n+1}+x^{3p}$$ is composite as it  is divisible by $$x^2+x+1$$ where $m,n,p$ are non-negative integers

Comment: @user140619, Unless $$m=n=p=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\, \ f = x^2+x+1\,$ divides $\!\!\!\!\overbrace{\color{#0a0}{x^{\rm\large 2+\color{#c00}3\:\!J}}+x^{\rm\large 1+\color{#c00}3\:\!K}+\color{#90f}{x^{\rm\large \color{#c00}3L^{\phantom{|}}\!}}}^{\textstyle {\rm e.g.}\ \ \color{#0a0}{x^5}\ +\,\ x\,\ +\,\ \color{#90f}1\ \ {\rm in\ OP}\, \ \ \ }\!\!\!\!\!\!\!= g\,$ by [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)

---

**Proof** $ $ [for completeness] $\  {\rm mod}\ f\!:\,\ 0\equiv (x\!-\!1)f\equiv x^{\large 3}-1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}\equiv 1},\,$ thus

$$\begin{eqnarray}\quad g\:\!  &&=\, x^{\large 2}\, (\color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}})^{\rm\large J}\! + x\,(\color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}})^{\rm\large K}\! + (\color{#c00}{x^{\large 3}})^{\rm\large L}\\ &&\equiv\, x^2\ \color{#c00}{(1)}\ \ +\ x\,\ \color{#c00}{(1)}\ \ +\ \ \color{#c00}{(1)}\equiv\, f\equiv\, 0\end{eqnarray}\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ If modular arithmetic is unfamiliar we can proceed equivalently as follows

$$ g - f = x^2\color{#c00}{(x^{\rm\large 3J}-1)} + x\color{#c00}{(x^{\rm\large 3K}-1)} + \color{#c00}{(x^{\rm\large 3L}-1)}\qquad$$

By the Factor Theorem each $\,\rm\color{#c00}{red}\,$ term is divisible by $\,x^3-1\,$ so also by $\,f,\,$ by $\,x^3-1 = (x\!-\!1)f.$ Thus since $f$ divides the RHS it divides the LHS, i.e.  $\,f\mid g-f\,$ so $\,f\mid (g-f)+f = g.$

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy method but you asked for a hint and I don't know how to tell you without giving the whole game away.

Let's try this: if you compute the expression for $n=0$ there is a very obvious prime factor $p$.  If you try it for $n=1$ the same prime is a factor.  If you now simplify $5^{5^k}$ modulo $p$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots\,$, the problem is practically solved.